# How do I make to start docker automatically after reboots?

Tags: centos, docker, centos-7

To start docker service manually one can use following command:

```
systemctl start docker
```

How do I make to start docker automatically after reboots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use once:

```
systemctl enable docker
```